# Load and use PKCS#8 Private Key

Tags: ios, rsa, private-key

I am currently generating and saving a key pair of RSA keys inside a Java REST Server using the following block of code:

```
        keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

        publicKey=keyPair.getPublic();
        publicKeyBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(publicKey.getEncoded()) ;

        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        privateKeyBase64 =  Base64.encodeBase64String(privateKey.getEncoded());
```

Now I want to use this same private key to decrypt another information returned from the server using an iOS client. As far as I know, the iOS does not provide great native support for RSA encryption. How can I decrypt information using this private key, supposing that I currently have the key encoded as a PKCS#8 Base64 string (like inside the variable privateKeyBase64)?

Thank you!

Comment: [This is supported on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW9), but I have a feeling what you want to do isn't a great idea. Ideally you would create the key on the *device*, not a REST service. For security purposes, you don't want the key to ever leave the device. Otherwise, it might be able to be intercepted by an attacker.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mike. The keys are not stored as plaintext inside the server, I encrypt them before. The user is the only person who can decrypt the key, I just not included that information to simplify the post :p I really don't want to generate the keys inside the client

Comment: Encrypt them using what key? If it's something the user sends in, it has a chance to be intercepted. Generating RSA keys on an iOS device is *fast*, if you use the Apple APIs. There's no reason not to do it.

Comment: I am using a AES generated key using the PKDF2 algorithm on the client side of the communication. This key is never sent to the server, so this will be no worry. I really don't want to generate the keys inside the iOS, the server will have another clients, such as laptop and Web Application and in a first stage the login (and RSA keys) are generated inside the WebApplication and sent encrypted to the Rest server.